# How to make your browser speed-up the load of you bundle.js?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I am developing a not [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (half PHP, half JS) where my `bundle.js` is quite big (>14MB) because I have some fonts, Kendo-UI, JQuery and other libraries to generate QR code on the fly embedded in my bundle. I noticed that on my PC.

When I change my route from `/foo` to `/bar`, I load a different page that load the very same `app.js`. Unfortunately, the delay is quite perceptible. It is about 1-3 seconds to load the page.

However if I reduce the size of this `bundle`, the load time is much shorter, but by looking at the network waterfall table, I notice that there is a huge delay between the reception of the avatar, to the load of the fonts.

According to Chrome, my `bundle` is loaded from memory cache, but still, 14 MB of JS not yet uglified seems to take between 1-3 seconds to be interpreted.

Does somebody can explain what happens and how I can solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: So you basically have a very, very, very large traditional web site, with full page reloads, all the resources are required for each page (ie. /foo & /bar) and need to optimize the load time. Please explain the connection to your reference of a (not) SPA?

Comment: With a SPA I only load my bundle once then the router running on the front end will only load components without all the JS libraries. Because I am not SPA, I have to load HTML pages and *reload* the bundle, the fonts and everything between each calls. I might take the direction of a SPA later on but for now I just would like to speed up the load and understand why Chrome is taking so long to process the `bundle.js` even though it is loaded from memory cache.

Comment: You've used the SPA bundling technique inappropriately. In a traditional web site layout that you have, you should optimize resource loading on per page basis. It is unlikely you need everything in the entire bundle on every page. My suggestion is to go back to a traditional design. Take advantage of async loading, delaying the load of images, CSS and javascript for any assets that are below the fold until after the page has rendered completely. Either that, or commit to building a SPA - you're stuck in middle right now and that is why it isn't working for you.